# How to make incoming call recors on asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

Situation: Analog phone line -> Asterisk with PSTN card -> Central PBX ->

```
exten => _1709,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=City_09)
exten => _1709,n,Noop(${CALLERID(name)})
exten => _1709,n,GoTo(incoming-reception,s,1)
```

Next

```
    [incoming-reception]
include => external-trunk
exten => 0027449999,1,GoTo(incoming-reception,s,1)
exten => anonymous,1,GoTo(incoming-reception,s,1)
;exten => s,1,GotoIfTime(9:00-18:00|mon-sat|*|*?incoming-reception-work,s,1)
exten => s,1,GotoIfTime(9:00-18:00|mon-fri|*|*?incoming-reception-work,s,1)
exten => s,n,Answer()
exten => s,n,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=2)
exten => s,n,NoOp(${CALLERID(num)})
exten => s,n,Set(CHANNEL(language)=ru)
exten => s,n,Wait(2)
exten => s,n,Background(day_off_1_welcome)
exten => s,n,Background(day_off_2_message)
exten => s,n,Voicemail(2001,s,300)
exten => 5,1,GoTo(incoming-reception-enoff,s,2)
exten => i,1,GoTo(incoming-reception,s,3)
exten => h,1,Congestion(10)
exten => h,2,HangUp()
```

next

```
[incoming-reception-work]
include => external-trunk
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Set(TIMEOUT(digit)=2)
exten => s,n,NoOp(${CALLERID(num)})
exten => s,n,Set(CHANNEL(language)=ru)
exten => s,n,Wait(2)
exten => s,n,Background(business_hours_1_welcome)
exten => s,n,Queue(test,T,,,32)
exten => s,n,Queue(test2,T)
exten => s,101,Background(business_hours_4_message)
exten => s,102,Voicemail(2001,s,300)
exten => 5,1,GoTo(incoming-reception-en,s,1)
exten => 9,1,Background(business_hours_4_message)
exten => 9,2,Voicemail(2001,s,300)
exten => i,1,GoTo(incoming-reception-work,s,1)
exten => h,1,Congestion(10)
exten => h,2,HangUp()
```

How can I make record incoming calls? Asterisk 1.8 (no freepbx, console only)

Comment: Acordinly to guidlines you have show some efforts. What exactly have you tried and what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [Monitor/StopMonitor](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_Monitor) dialplan procedures to record incoming calls. Use the following template:

```
same => n,Monitor(wav,''${UNIQUEID},m)
same => n,Set(FILEARG="/tmp/asterisk/monitor/${UNIQUEID}.wav")
.
.         
same => n,Hangup()
exten => h,1,StopMonitor()
same => n,System(/usr/local/bin/record-file-to-database --file=${FILEARG})
```

Check your Asterisk configs for the exact location of Monitor output folder.

See also an example [here](https://github.com/grwlf/asterisk-dongle-setup/blob/a1cc08ba316e98e45b764c6235e79f6e3ef98136/default.nix#L384)